# global arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3];

function foo(x,y,a)
    return @. x+y+a
end

bar(x,y) = foo(x,y,a);

bar(1,2)

function tar(x,y)
    a = [3,4,5] 
    bar(x,y)
end

tar(1,2)
```

Because of rigid design I want to  call `bar` from another function which can only take 2 arguments and change the value of `a`.

How can I change the code in order to update `a` without changing the function number of arguments?

Given that the size of the array will be fixed to 3 components, could I use a `const array` to do this? What are the risks of using it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you never want to have global variables that are updated as a side-effect of other functions. This is a very ugly design pattern. The only scenario I could think of where such pattern is might be acceptable if this is some initialization where a package is loaded (eg. information on linked resources etc.) - in this case the global variable will be however global within a package not the entire Julia shell.

Having that said your code should be:

```
const a = [1,2,3];

function tar(x,y)
    a .= [3,4,5] 
    # ... do whatever
end
```

Knowing `a` has fixed size you could also try `using StaticArrays`:

```
const a2 = @MVector [1,2,3]

function tar(x,y)
    a2 .= (3,4,5)
    # ... do whatever
end
```

If you are more into "replacing" the entire variable have a look into references:

```
const aref = Ref([1,2,3])

function tar(x,y)
    aref[] = [3,4]
    # ... do whatever
end
```

Having that said - avoid global variables, usually you do not need them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will the `const aref = Ref([1,2,3])` have a great impact on performance? Or would it be more efficient with `StaticArrays` ? Are any of them safe to work with parallel processing?

Comment: You can do `Ref(@SVector [1,2,3])`. Static arrays are faster than normal arrays and immutable data is faster than mutable data. Whether you use Ref or not depends on whether you want to replace the entire object.